# Focus loss in electron-based apps in Manjaro Xfce on Alt push

Tags: linux, electron, slack, xfce, manjaro

While using electron based apps, like slack or gpmdp, when I type something in input field and switch keyboard layout (I use `Alt+Shift`), pushing `Alt` causes focus to move onto menubar selection.

So typing anything containing 2 languages is infuriating.

How to disable focus loss?

Comment: There is a type in the title: `elecron` instead of `electron`

Answer (score 0):

I faced with this issue in Zulip v5.4.2 and Postman v7.30.1.

My [workaround](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/22213#issuecomment-681831167) of this Electron's bug:

#### On Linux

0. Close Zulip
1. Find the Zulip's resource folder. For example: `cd /opt/Zulip/resources`
2. Make backup of app.asar file
   `cp app.asar app.asar.bak`
3. Unpack the app.asar archive
   `npx asar extract app.asar app-unpacked`
4. Find the menu.js file and edit it, add the & symbol into the menu label
   `nano ./app-unpacked/app/main/menu.js`
5. Change

- `label: t.__('File')` to `label: t.__('&File')`
- `label: t.__('Edit')` to `label: t.__('&Edit')`
- And so on for each top menu items

6. Then pack the app-unpacked folder back into asap archive
   `mv app.asar app_old.asar`
   `npx asar pack app-unpacked app.asar`
7. Run Zulip and check Alt+Shift

#### On Windows

You can use the 7zip archiver with the [asap plugin](https://www.tc4shell.com/en/7zip/asar/)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it did not help: seems like slack has these parts packed with minifier.